# Store client-side data, making it available to a service worker

Tags: offline-caching, service-worker

In my **node.js chat app**, I want to save chat data in **offline mode** and push notification when **online**. Basic chat app is done. I'm using **ws** node module for server code. In client side code, I want to use **service worker** for storing offline data. I have done some home work https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/ https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/making-an-offline-webapp-with-service-workers.html, but I think I don't understand how can I store chat data in **service worker** offline data.

Answer (score 5):

[IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) is a general purpose database that's available client-side in both the service worker and main web page context. I'd suggest using that to store data like chat messages.

There are a number of libraries out there that wrap IndexedDB to make the interface friendlier. A relatively newer one, [`idb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb), has the advantage of providing a promise-based interface, which comes in handy when using IndexedDB from a service worker, since so much of the asynchronous code there is already promise-based.

Answer (score 2):

Once I also have to faced that type of problem. So what I do, is some kind of cheating. I create an object in **IndexedDB** where I store every chat data temporally and after successfully send my chat data to server, I immediately delete my **IndexedDB** data. If chat data failed to send to server, it cannot delete temporally **IndexedDB** data. And when server is available to receive chat data, first check **IndexedDB** data and send to saved chat data (if any left).

**NB:** this is not accurate solution, not even close.